# How to implement Active Directory based SSO with electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How can I grab domain user security context (username etc.) in electron app running under Windows?

I know I can use environment variables (process.env.USER), but I don't think it's secure.

Answer (score 5):

A proper answer would depend on many different aspects of your environment, but here some ideas.

**Passportjs**
[Passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) is a goto package for nodejs authentication. With a bit of googling, I found that Microsoft has created a github repo called [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) with strategies (the interfaces passportjs uses to connect to things) specifically for Azure AD authentication. So if you're using Azure AD, passport-azure-ad is a good way to go.

**A passport-azure-ad Issue**
If not, and you try to use passport-azure-ad to authenticate to ADFS, WS-FED, or SAML you will likely run into [this issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/issues/25#issuecomment-97146062). In short, it is not supported by that repo.

**Passport-ldapauth**
So in that case, have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439030/passport-active-directory-node-js) describing how to use the passport-ldapauth strategy to authenticate to ADFS. It doesn't seem to be too difficult, though there are some "gotchas" to watch out for. There are also other good suggestions for OAuth, and further explanation on passport-ldapauth by the owner of that repo.

While I haven't used passport-ldapauth, I've done many AD/LDAP integrations over the years and LDAP is a well known and well documented method of authentication, and it is reasonably secure. [This article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/ldap-security-problems) is a good example of the security concerns to be mindful of when using LDAP. However, these concerns are regarding the use of the protocol and are not related to the Passport-ldapauth package directly.

---

#### Update:

As of Electron version 0.35.0 the new [app.allowNTLMCredentialsForAllDomains(allow)](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appallowntlmcredentialsforalldomainsallow) may also effect your situation. According to the docs it allows you to dynamically set whether to always send HTTP NTLM credentials or negotiate them normally. There is also a disclaimer about this option not working on some "badly configured" networks, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: When I tell Electron to loadUrl() and that url is behind SSO (ADFS) I simply get an unauthorized response.  In a standard browser I would get a standard basic auth prompt, enter my user/pass and then see the page.  Is this related?  If so, you mean I have to basically create a server that would communicate and handle this ADFS for me?

Comment: If you use passportjs, any failure (including configuration errors) will result in a standard 401 unauthorized response. Have you looked for errors in the dev tools?

Comment: Also, nodejs is typically server-side. So by implementing passportjs, yes, you are creating a "server" that handles the necessary authentication, tokens, etc.